# Azure-pipelines `- script: ...` how to split a command without spaces to multiple lines

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am looking for a way to make a multiline script like:

```yaml
steps:
  - script: >
      echo foo
      bar
```

result in:

```
foobar
```

with no spaces or newlines.

---

In the real-world scenario I am defining a variable like so:

```
  - script: >
      echo
      "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageVersion]
      some_very_long_awk_code_to_generate_a_3_digit_number"
```

This issue is causing it to include a space, so the stored variable will become  `some_very_...` (note the space at the start). The ">" next to the script will add spaces where there are newlines, but there seems to be no method to just join it without a space or newline.

[This explanation about YAML multiline code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/9530045) explains that it should work as follows:

```yaml
steps:
  - script: >
      echo foo\
      bar
```

Unfortunately, this also results in:

```
foo bar
```

Performing it with a double quote:

```yaml
steps:
  - script: >
      echo "foo\
      bar"
```

will result in:

```
foo\ bar
```

Answer (score 0):

> Azure-pipelines `- script: ...` does not support multiline code with no spaces and no newlines

The document [about YAML multiline code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/9530045) is used for parameter, but this doesn't work in the output syntax `echo`.

And when you create a default YAML pipeline with Starter piepline:

[image]

There is a demo code about **multi-line script**:

```
steps:

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'
```

So, if you want make a multiline script, you could try to use below scripts:

```
- script: |
    echo foo
    echo bar
```

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at the demo. So 'parameters' are parsed different then 'script' content? It's all YAML right?
So how can you make it combine multiline script without a newline or space? The example you give at the end simple executes both, but what I want to see is "fooecho bar" to be returned.

Comment: @Siete, You could use `- script: |
    echo echofoo
    echo bar`

Comment: Looking back at this, I think I phrased my question incorrectly. What I am looking for is breaking a very long line of code with no spaces, into multiple lines for readability. But any newline I add will result in a space when the `- script:` input is parsed.